# "have been here" vs. "have been being here"

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, present-continuous

Which one is correct? I know the present perfect continuous tense is for what. My question is here that we should use that tense when we want to say "I was here (a city) for ten years and now I am here as well" we must use the present perfect continuous but we use the present perfect (I've seen in the grammar books):

> I have been here for ten years.
>
> vs.
>
> I have been being here for ten years.

Comment: I have been being is not correct English.

Comment: @anouk please explain more. How can we convert this sentence to the present perfect continuous type? "I am here."

Comment: I have been here for 10 years is the correct sentence.

Comment: @anouk it is in the present perfect tense. But being here started ten years ago and it still continues. This definition is exactly about the present perfect continuous.

Comment: whether used in the present perfect simple or continuous "to be" becomes "has been", not has been being.

Comment: @anouk please make a response to the question that I accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I have been being here* is not idiomatic.

You have probably learned that there is a category of verbs which are only very rarely used in with the progressive/continuous construction: stative verbs like *be*, *know*, *live*, *see* which express a state rather than an action or event. These verbs have the fundamental sense of a continuing state (which is what the progressive/continuous construction expresses) built into their meanings, so the progressive/continuous is superfluous.

For the same reason these verbs are rarely used with the progressive/continuous **perfect** construction. Indeed, there is even stronger pressure to avoid the progressive/continuous perfect, because the perfect is also inherently stative: it designates a state which came into being as a result of a prior action or event.

Saying *I have been being here for ten years* thus adds nothing to the sense of *I have been being here for ten years*, so **we don't say it**.

Furthermore: These "rules", like most "rules" of grammar, are not absolute: there are exceptions. But lexical *be* (that is, *be* as a main verb, not a component of the progressive or passive construction) is exceptionally resistant to exception, because it is the most "stative" of verbs: it ordinarily expresses nothing beyond a particular state. In consequence, when lexical *be* is cast in the progressive construction it usually has a different meaning, approximately "temporarily behave":

> "John is being a jerk" does not mean that *John **is** a jerk* but that  *John is **behaving like** a jerk* right now.

Comment: As you have said, "John is being a jerk" usually carries an idiomatic meaning equivalent to "John is behaving like a jerk." Yet picture the following exchange of dialogue: "Are you all so invested in your uninterrupted communion with the Eternal Now that your only behaviors are ongoing existential fulfillments of your individual states of being, relative to those around you?" "Yes. Caroline is being a mother. Hillary is being a diva. John is being a jerk." This is an example of the unusual stative usage.

Answer (score 4):

> I have been being here for ten years.

While I believe this is *technically* grammatical (in terms of syntax alone), it is essentially never used, and so is ungrammatical for all practical purposes.

You can, however, use a different verb that would impart *almost* the same meaning and be acceptable:

> I have been **existing** here for ten years.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems I see is that “have been” is a form of the verb “is,” which doesn’t really combine well with the verb “be” because of their respective applications in English. For instance, you wouldn’t say, “I am being here;” you would just say, “I am here.” This connects with the fact that the words “is” and “be” sometimes overlap in terms of meaning and usage, which complicates their relationship to each other.

Comment: That does not seem to add much to the explanations given by previous users.