# What tense is the main clause of the following English sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

> Of all the changes that have taken place in English-language
> newspapers during the past quarter-century, perhaps the most
> far-reaching has been the inexorable decline in the scope and
> seriousness of their arts coverage.

I am learning to analyze long and short sentences in English.

In the above sentence, the preceding that introduces the attributive clause.
`Of all the changes` is a prepositional phrase as an adverbial. The latter part should be the main clause.

perhaps the most far-reaching (change) has been the inexorable decline in the scope and seriousness of their arts coverage

I'm curious if the main clause here is the present perfect tense? `Decline` here should be a noun because the adjective `inexorable` is in front of it.

But the structure of the present perfect tense should be:
Present perfect tense: has done
present perfect continuous tense: has been doing

What is the usage of `has been noun`?

Thanks

Comment: Why have you introduced the auxiliary verbs *has **done*** and *has been **doing*** when analysing ***has been*** in the cited text? In principle, something like *The decline [**has been being**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/200875/have-been-here-vs-have-been-being-here) inexorable* is probably syntactically valid, but you'd normally only encounter forms like that in "Indian English".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple present: The most far-reaching change is the decline in something.

present perfect: The most far-reaching change has been the decline in something.

The struture you mentioned for present perfect tense could be changed to "have/has + past participle". Here "been" is the past participle of "is".

Answer (score 0):

`Of all the changes` **preposition/adverbial/attributive** meaning *outstanding from a global perspective*
`inexorable decline`  **adjective-noun**
`has been`   **present perfect progressive**

**Noun** `has been`  = person or thing considered to be outdated or became insignificant

Comment: How is **has been** the present perfect progressive?  I don't see any progressive in there.  Progressive would be like *has been working*, *has been sleeping*, etc.

Comment: progressive to the present, but not necessarily the future or continuous from the past

Comment: What I'm saying is that *has been* isn't the present perfect progressive, because [PPP is the name of a specific tense](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/present-perfect-continuous-tense/), and "has been <noun phrase>" isn't it, because there is no present participle in it.

Comment: "is" is reflected at the time of writing, perhaps in today's era for present tense implied. That is what I meant @stangdon  progressing from the *has been* past.  Does this suggest  that the trend is continuing or has stopped or just unknown?